# Two dimensional input in GA syntax for the lower and upper bound

Tags: genetic-algorithm, lower-bound, upperbound

I am using GA to minimize the objective function which has 24 design variables. All the variables have only upper and lower bounds but last 4 variables have x and y axis constraint. How to do this in MatLab Since the bound constraint can only be feed to GA as a vectors. 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

if your variables are dependent on x and y then you can try to find the min and max value of variable for given range of values of x and y and then use those values to define upper and lower bound